# knex returning empty result when using regex_matches

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

knex is returning empty result when using regex_matches although the generated SQL returns the correct result set.  using knexv2.3.0 and pg8.2.1.

i.e.

knex("v_domains").select("domain_uuid", knex.raw("(REGEXP_MATCHES(domain_description, 'rid:(.*?)//'))[1] as reseller_id")).debug(true)

{
method: 'select',
options: {},
timeout: false,
cancelOnTimeout: false,
bindings: [],
__knexQueryUid: 'ROyC62-HHob0AiJzffMee',
sql: `select "domain_uuid", (REGEXP_MATCHES(domain_description, 'rid:(.*?)//'))[1] as reseller_id from "v_domains"`
}

any help on this would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the answer.   I feel slightly depressed knowing how many hours I wasted trying to figure this out.  Don't write code when you are tired kids. ;)

```
const test = await knex("v_domains").select("domain_uuid", knex.raw(" 
(REGEXP_MATCHES(domain_description, ?))[1] as reseller_id", ['rid: 
(.*?)\/\/'])).debug(true);
```